Moving Script to php
I have a php form that sends times to Google Sheets.  The times are the first and last listed in the script.
$provider    = Person::find($request->person_id);
$person_name = $person->firstname.' '.$person->lastname;
$sheetObj->range('A'.$row)->update([[
  $request->workdate,
  "",
  "",
  "",
  $request->Completed,
  "",
  "",
  $request->first,
  "",
  $request->last,
  "",
  $request->self,
  "",
  "",
  $person_name,
]]);
}

I have the below Google Apps Script that changes the time format of the time that is passed after it is entered into the Google Sheet.
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const ss = e.source;
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange("H3:H").setNumberFormat('h":"mm" "am/pm');
  sheet.getRange("J3:J").setNumberFormat('h":"mm" "am/pm');
}

Is it possible to run this script in the php code instead of the Google Apps Script?  I'm having an issue with the script running without interacting with the cells.

PHP can produce date and time data in any almost format you want, but that's not what you're doing here. You're changing the format that Sheets is using to display. You can't do that in PHP.

You can use date($format, $timestamp) which converts a Unix $timestamp to the format you pass in. As $request->first and $request->last are already formatted, you can convert them to Unix timestamps with strtotime($datetime).
// Function to format time to 'h:mm am/pm'
function formatTime($time) {
    return date('g:i a', strtotime($time));
}

$formatted_first_time = formatTime($request->first);
$formatted_last_time = formatTime($request->last);


Edit:
Try something like this. It should change the format of columns H and J from the 3rd row to h:mm am/pm format. Let me know if there's something missing!
use Google\Client;
use Google\Service\Sheets;

$client = new Google\Client();
$client->setScopes(Google\Service\Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);
$client->setAuthConfig('path/to/credentials.json');
$sheets = new Google\Service\Sheets($client);

$spreadsheetId = 'your-spreadsheet-id';

// Create the request to update the number format
$requestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest([
    'requests' => [
        new Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
            'repeatCell' => [
                'range' => [
                    'sheetId' => $sheetId,
                    'startRowIndex' => 2,
                    'startColumnIndex' => 7, // H column
                    'endColumnIndex' => 8, // H column
                ],
                'cell' => [
                    'userEnteredFormat' => [
                        'numberFormat' => [
                            'type' => 'TIME',
                            'pattern' => 'h:mm am/pm',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'fields' => 'userEnteredFormat.numberFormat',
            ],
        ]),
        new Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
            'repeatCell' => [
                'range' => [
                    'sheetId' => $sheetId,
                    'startRowIndex' => 2,
                    'startColumnIndex' => 9, // J column
                    'endColumnIndex' => 10, // J column
                ],
                'cell' => [
                    'userEnteredFormat' => [
                        'numberFormat' => [
                            'type' => 'TIME',
                            'pattern' => 'h:mm am/pm',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'fields' => 'userEnteredFormat.numberFormat',
            ],
        ]),
    ],
]);

$response = $sheets->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $requestBody);


It passed the time in the correct format. (07:00 am), but Google Sheets still isn't reading it as a time.  It shows as '07:00 am when sent to Google Sheets.

I've just edited the answer with some code that should allow you to change the format of the sheet cells from within PHP which is done through the Google Sheets API, so make sure you have the API and credentials all set-up.
